# Transitive function in DCG

Tags: prolog, dcg

Is it possible to make a transitive function like the following in DCG? Or to combine it with a DCG rule?

```
genx(A,B) :- gen(A,B).
genx(A,C) :- gen(A,B), genx(B,C).
gen(a,b).
gen(b,c).
```

I will explain what i'm trying to do exactly :

If i have this grammar:

```
noun_phrase(D,N) --> det(D), noun(N).
noun(n(cat)) --> [cat].
```

I want to make some restriction like if i want `N` in `noun(N)` to be an animal. So i can use something like this:

```
noun_phrase(np(D,N)) --> det(D), noun(N), genx(N, animal).
```

Where the information of a cat is an animal is inferenced from some facts like:

```
gen(cat,pet).
gen(pet,animal).
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to undestand.

If I'm not wrong, from the formal point of view the rules

```
genx(A,B) :- gen(A,B).
genx(A,C) :- gen(A,B), genx(B,C).
```

can be written in DCG syntax as

```
genx --> gen.
genx --> gen, genx.
```

and, with facts,

```
gen(a, b).
gen(b, c).
```

`genx(a, c)` should return true.

However, the `A`, `B`, `C` in DCG are intended to be list.

I don't know if is reasonable to use DCG (that is intended for parsing) in this way to implement algebrical rules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work! Can you give a more clear answer?

Comment: @user2598997 - wich prolog are you using? I see it working with gprolog and with swi-prolog. If the not list is a problem, you can try changing facts in `gen([a], [b]).` and `gen([b], [c]).`; `genx([a], [c])` should return true.

Comment: I'm using swi-prolog (the online vserion). genx(A, B) --> gen(A, B). genx(A, C) --> gen(A, B), genx(B, C). gen([a], [b]). gen([b], [c]). gives this error: procedure `genx(A,B)' does not exist.

Comment: @user2598997 - look at my answer; if you use DCG, you have to remove the two arguments; so `genx --> gen, genx.`, not `genx(A, C) --> gen(A, B), genx(B, C).`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this cannot be useful in my case if i can't use arguments, i won't be able to do genx(N, animal) like in the example above.

Comment: @user2598997 - You're wellcome; I'm not sure but I suspect that DCG syntax isn't useful for your needs.